# org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'The token is invalid

Tags: java

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(GoogleApi.class)
                .apiKey("198898816518.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .apiSecret("hpvFCWHt6ZxWqO-DLwF062rO")
                .scope(SCOPE)
                .build();

        Token requestToken = null;

        requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

        System.out.println("authorize Scribe here:");
        Token token = new Token("oauth_token", "4/qGH3cNdzrdIIMmEsDMTRNhKD9z51");
        System.out.println(AUTHORIZE_URL + requestToken.getToken());
        System.out.println("paste the verifier");

              Verifier verifier = new Verifier("IWqonDH9RCtK0hwyZQlYOUCb");
                      // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token

        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(token, verifier);
```

i got the error..

> org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect.
>   Can't extract token and secret from this: 'The token is invalid.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be using scribe 1.3.0 as I also got such kinda error doing oauth stuff. Just replace it with the latest version, scribe 1.3.1 and you will be fine....seems like some gotcha in 1.3.0...not sure exactly abt the error cause but this worked for me.
You can download from here : [scribe 1.3.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe/1.3.1)